# PhpStorm Smart Key not working in .env file

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm IDE, I want to comment line with smart key for multiple lines for .env file.

I am using CTRL+Q smart key for comment line. It is working fine everywhere but not working in .env file.

What should I do about it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install a plugin for .env file support, for example this one works:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9525--env-files-support

It also highlights your code and has some other short keys as well.